# CSS defining multiple font-sizes

Tags: html, css, fonts

My website is using a viewport size (vw) for font-sizes.

As many know already, however, vw doesn't work in some browsers..

So I want to define 1 additional font-size for my html tags, in case the user's browser doesn't support vw sizes..

Is there a way to do this?

I was thinking something like

```
font-size: 1vw 1em;
```

but apparently this doesn't work, since 1em would specify line-height instead of font-size..

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply specify the fallback value with less support first:

```
span {
    font-size: 10em;
    font-size: 10vw;
}
```

If the browser doesn't support `vw` units, the `font-size` will be `10em`.

If you want to see this in action, try viewing [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/q5s2pvx1/) in IE8/7.

```css
span {
    font-size: 10em;
    font-size: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<span>If the browser doesn't support vw units, the font-size will be 10em</span>
```